# Cross-updating issue with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I have an "cross-update" issue with knockout. The following function ('self.applyTagsAllocation') causes some strange effect. Line 3: 'scenetag.sceneID = scene.sceneID;' is updating 'tag.sceneID' as well as the local scenetag-variable. I really cannot understand why as sceneID never is an observable.

```
self.applyTagsAllocation = function (tag) {
        var  scenetag = tag;
        var scene = self.selectedScene();
        scenetag.sceneID = scene.sceneID;  
        scene.sceneTags.push(scenetag);
};
```

Here´s a more complete listing of my viewmodel:

```
var Tag = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = data.ID || -1;      
    self.sceneID = data.sceneID;
    self.text = ko.observable((data.text || 'new').trim()); 
    self.tagType = ko.observable(data.tagType || -1 );
}

var Scene = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.sceneID = data.sceneID;
    self.sceneTags = ko.observableArray();

    self.tags = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            var tags = [];
            tags.push.apply(tags, self.sceneTags());
            return tags;
        },
        write: function (tag) {
            this.sceneTags.push(tag);
        },
        owner: self
    });
};

var ViewModel = function (model){
    var self = this;

    self.selectedScene = ko.observable();
    self.sceneTags = ko.observableArray();

    self.Scenes = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(model, function (item) {
            return new Scene(item);
        }));

    self.sceneTags = ko.computed(function () { 
        var tags = [];
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Scenes(), function (scene) {
            tags.push.apply(tags, scene.tags());   
        });
        return tags;
    });


    //Tag is first created with:
    self.addSceneTag = function (name, type) {   
        if (!type) type = -1;
        var newtag = new Tag({
            ID: -1,
            sceneID: self.selectedScene().sceneID,
            text: name,    
            tagType: type
        });

        // already in use?
        var abort = false;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedScene().sceneTags(), function (tag) {
            if (tag.text() === newtag.text()) abort = true;
        });
        if (!abort) self.selectedScene().sceneTags.push(newtag);
    };

    self.applyTagsAllocation = function (tag) {
        var  scenetag = tag;
        var scene = self.selectedScene();
        scenetag.sceneID = scene.sceneID;  
        scene.sceneTags.push(scenetag);
    };
};
```

(You might wonder why 'Scene' has both a sceneTags-array and a tags-array. This is because I have done a simplification in this example. In my project I have another tag-type and the two types are merged together in the viewmodel-scope.)

HTML

Tag is first set up with:

```
<input class="taginput"  placeholder="&lt;add a tag&gt;" data-bind="textInput: tagname, event: {keyup: $root.inputTag}" />
```

Then when tag exists I want to add it onto another ‘scene’ from the scope of «foreach: tag» with:

```
 <span data-bind="visible: sceneID  !== null &&  sceneID !== $root.selectedScene().sceneID, click: function(){$root.applyTagsAllocation($data)};">Add Tag</span>
```

The actual foreach here is a loop within the knockout-sortable (from Ryan Niemeyer):

```
<div class="tag-list" data-bind="sortable:{template:'tagsTmpl',data:$root.sceneTags"></div>
```

What can be causing this? 
Any hints and clues highly appreciated!

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have another look at the function; in your view you bind the `$data` for a tag to the `self.applyTagsAllocation` function, which essentially does this =>

```
self.applyTagsAllocation = function (tag) {
   var scenetag = tag; // scenetag == instance of Tag you passed ( $data )
   var scene = self.selectedScene(); // scene == the selected instance of Tag
   scenetag.sceneID = scene.sceneID;  //!!!! This line says:
   // 'Make sceneID of this instance = sceneID of the selected instance'
   scene.sceneTags.push(scenetag); // will fail, you can't write to a simple computed
};
```

So yes, it updates the local variable, but the local variable points to your `Tag` viewModel, and so it updates the object.. Unlike you might have (seemed to have) thought, assigning an object to another variable doesn't clone it; it is merely a reference.

Rather do:

```
self.applyTagsAllocation = function (tag) {
   var scenetag = {};
   // clone an object, for whatever strange reason one could have:
   for (var prop in tag) {
      scenetag[prop] = tag[prop];
   } // now you have a copy of the tag instance you passed [..] rest of function
};
```

Or if you wanted to set the tag as selected, which I would deem more logical:
`self.selectedScene(tag)` in your function.

**Important**: you have assigned `self.sceneTags` twice, and the second time it was a computed observable. You can't write to computed observables (while in `applyTagsAllocation` you push to it), then you need pureComputed..

Comment: Hi @Tyblitz! Thank you very much for your answer. Your suggestion with the cloning seems to do the trick. Brilliant. I am so grateful! :)

Comment: Just thought of another possible approach: instead of the cloning I could use "tag" to instantiate a new Tag-object with the same attributes, except self.selectedScene().sceneID, could´t I?
Then I probably should rewrite 'self.addSceneTag' to include both functionalities.

Comment: @AsleG that you could do as well; In your constructor you could do `var Tag = function (data, flag) { self.sceneID = flag === true ? data.sceneID || '';` If you don't wish to include it in the constructor you can create a new tag with all props `var x = new Tag(data);` and reassign the sceneID afterwards, eg `x.sceneID = ''` or should you wish to remove the prop altogether `delete x.sceneID`.